# How to add https to the image urls that are added from the web page to the database in laravel

Tags: laravel

In my laravel project there is a option of adding a book using ISBN number in my web page. I have added a book image from the web page using its ISBN number and its url is stored in the database as http but I want to load that url as https. Now I could not find how that book will be loaded as https. Can anyone tell me?

here is the code in my book controller to store and show the book:-

```
public function store(BookRequest $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();
    $ISBN = isset($validatedData['isbn']) ? $validatedData['isbn'] : null;
    $stored = Book::firstOrCreate(['isbn' => $ISBN], $validatedData);
    return response()->json(['error'=> !$stored]);
}

public function show(Book $book)
{
    return view('knowledgecafe.library.books.show', compact('book'));
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to display the image of the book, please.

Comment: This code does not contain any image urls

Answer (score 0):

You should first upload an image on the secured server and then get URL of that image and store that URL in the database.

If your server is secured server then you will get URL with https.